# Obtaining selectedItem in JComboBox and inserting as one value in query Newbie

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jcombobox

I can't find a way of putting all the selected items on 3 different combobox which I need to insert as query to Java DB(derby). Here's my code.

int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog
        (null, "Do you want to add the employee?","Confirm",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

```
    if(response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){

        try{
        String url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/EMPLOYEEINFO [ADMIN1 on ADMIN1]";
        String username="ADMIN1";
        String password="ADMIN1";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        String Query = 
        "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_ID,EMP_LASTNAME,EMP_FIRSTNAME,EMP_MIDDLENAME,ADDRESS,POSITION ) "
                +"VALUES "
                + "(' "+AddEmployee_EmployeeID_TxtField.getText()+" ',"
                + " ' "+AddEmployee_LastName_TxtField.getText()+" ',"
                + " ' "+AddEmployee_FirstName_TxtField.getText()+" ',"
                + " ' "+AddEmployee_MiddleName_TxtField.getText()+" ',"
                + " ' "+AddEmployee_Address_TxtField.getText()+" '"
                + " ' "+AddEmployee_Position_TxtField.getText()+" ',"
                + " ' "+AddEmployee_Gender_ComboBox.getSelectedItem()+"')"
                ;
        stat.execute(Query);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Insert Success!");
```

And below is the screenshot. I'm thinking of getselectedObject but i have 3 combo boxes so I really don't know how. Please help.

I need to get the selected items of Month, Day and Year of the Birthday then insert it to my table in Derby. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: @ChrisFranklin, thanks again. Here's what i did per your advise. 

    private String getBirthdayFromComboBoxes() {
        Object month = AddEmployee_BirthdayMonth_ComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        Object day = AddEmployee_BirthdayDay_ComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        Object year = AddEmployee_BirthdayYear_ComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        // Format this the way your database expects.
        String formattedDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
        return formattedDate;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a separate method to get the fields and combine the values into a formatted date. Something like this:

```
private String getDateFromFields() {
  String month = monthComboBox.getSelectedItem();
  String day = dayComboBox.getSelectedItem();
  String year = yearComboBox.getSelectedItem();
  // Format this the way your database expects.
  String formattedDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
}
```

You just call this method and you will get back the formatted date string that you can use in your query. Change the variable names of the combo box fields to match your names and format the string into what your database expects and you should be good to go!

Comment: I thank you very much. My knowledge is a bit limited to common functions. I didn't know about formatting or the "/" This solved my problem. But i had to change the String to Object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
String bDay=dayCombo.getSelectedItem()+"-"+monthCombo.getSelectedItem()+"-"+yearCombo.getSelectedItem();
```

But I will recommend you to use [JDatechooser](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jcalendar/jcalendar-1.4.jar.zip) in this case.

```
JDateChooser bDayChooser =new JDateChooser();
bDayChooser.setDateFormatString("dd-MM-yyyy");//format visible date of the date chooser as you need
String bDay=((JTextField) bDayChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).
                getText();
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the help. I'm not familiar yet with JDateChooser but I will definitely take your advise. I'm still learning. All of you guys are helping me a lot learn faster.  Thanks.